# warn Package native-base contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building react-native app for the first time. I want to use native-base so I followed the document : https://docs-v2.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html

```
>> npm install native-base@2 --save

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

added 39 packages, and audited 1153 packages in 10s

139 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

> > react-native link

warn Package native-base contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
error: unknown command 'link'

I have tried below few ways, but still no luck

```
>> npx react-native-asset
its giving error as : cannot find module 'react-native.config.js'

I could not get this config file as well. 

next I have deleted node modules and did npm install again, still the same error: unknown command 'link'

Please suggest solution.
```

Answer (score -1):

for me, when `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start` and go such error, the cause is:

I just add some in dependencies of `package.json` manually edit no by `npm install`